# Android, clear text values of editTexts' id and views which are created dynamically onResume

Tags: android, android-activity, dynamically-generated, onresume, onbackpressed

I have an activity where I dynamically create `EditText` and set an id dynamically,

```
Iterator iterator = List.iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext())
    {
    ....
    editTextExample.generateViewId();

    }
```

When I go to the next activity and come back(`onBackPressed()`) , I want to clear the text values in the dynamically generated `EditText` which the user has entered when the previous activity is resumed(`onResume()`)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Save your ids

```
ArrayList<Integer> mIds = new ArrayList<>(List.size())
...
while (iterator.hasNext())
{
    ...
    int id = View.generateViewId();
    editTextExample.setId(id);
    mIds.add(id);
}
```

and clear their contents:

```
void onResume () {
   for (int id: mIds)
     findViewById(id).setText("");
}
```

Comment: This helped me , Thanks. However , setting id dynamically using generateViewId didn't work (at some point the text values were not getting cleared)  instead i used an int value for id and store that in mIds List.

Comment: Looks like you didn't assign result of `generateViewId()` to your EditText instances. like `id = View.generateViewId(); editTextExample.setId(id); mIds.add(id)`

Comment: Using positive int values for view ids is fine as far as you can guarantee there will be no conflicts. `generateViewId` guaranties.

Comment: I missed setting the generated id to the view. it worked Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following activity call back methods are called, after pressing back button.

```
onPause()
onStop()
onDestroy()
```

The activity is destroyed.

And it recreates when launched again. These are the callback methods when it launches again.

```
onCreate()
onStart()
onResume()
```

So you can clear all edittext in  `onResume()` method.

Happy coding!!